# Google script - Submit form response without having authorization to edit form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a script for collaborators, to be used in google sheets.
When they trigger the script, it submits a form response, that then gets used to modify a "central" spread sheet.

But I am faced with a permission problem, and I haven't managed to find a convenient answer to it on the net.

The script uses `FormApp.openById([...]).createResponse().[....].submit().`

The problem comes from the fact both `openById()` and `openByUrl()` need the person who runs the script to be able to edit the form.

(As said on the Class FormApp help page : *Returns the Form with the specified URL. Throws an exception if the URL is invalid or the user does not have permission to open the form.*)

I have so far found 2 workarounds :

- Give edit access for the form to my collaborators : it then shares them a form they shouldn't edit.
- Change the link-sharing of the form to "on" : although no one but me actually knows the form Id, I don't really like the possibility of anyone discovering the link to be able to edit the form.

Neither of these workarounds completely satisfies me, and I'm sure there must be a way to submit a response via a script without being able to edit the form - just as people who send answers to google forms can't generally edit the questions ! Just I can't figure out how.

Any help on this problem will be very much appreciated !

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Create a Web App using an account with owner or editor access to the form and set it to be run as the script owner. For a general guide see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web